# How to forward upstream from nginx to upstream server

Tags: nginx, docker, ejabberd, docker-compose

I am trying to reverse-proxy an ejabberd connection manager with nginx in docker.

Following is my docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - ejabberd
    links:
      - ejabberd
  ejabberd:
    image: ejabberd:16.04
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "5280:5280"
    links:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

The images **nginx**, **ejabberd:16.04** and **mysql:5.6** are available in my local docker.

Following is my server config file which is included in the nginx.conf file

```
upstream ejabberd-server {
        server ejabberd:5280;
}
server {
    # regular silverstripe things here

    # location should match your JabberPage::BOSHUrl
    # with a leading slash
    listen 80;
    #server_name oops.hereim.co

    location /http-bind {
        # Local ejabberd with http-bind
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://ejabberd-server;
    }

}
```

But when I try to access the url ***http://192.168.99.102/http-bind***

I get the error 404 not found.

Am I missing something in the configuration above?

**192.168.99.102** is the IP of my docker machine.

```
docker-compose exec nginx ping ejabberd
```

The above command returns a reply.

The upstream has to be setup to host ejabberd as nginx and ejabberd are not on the same ejabberd container.

If you see the docker-compose.yml, the ejabberd and mysql connection works fine and I am able to connect to mysql from ejabberd. But there seems to be some missing piece while connection nginx to ejabberd.

Comment: is your ejabberd-server up and running ?

Comment: Yes, The ejabberd server is up and running.

Comment: It would help to isolate the problem with the multiple moving parts. Is http://192.168.99.102/ talking to nginx. Is http://127.0.0.1:5200/ bringing up ejabberd? Does `docker-compose exec nginx ping ejabberd` respond?

Comment: @BMitch I have edited the question for more information. The command
`docker-compose exec nginx ping ejabberd` returns a response

Comment: You didn't mention if you are able to directly talk to ejabberd or nginx, this is needed to identify which of those is throwing the 404.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below rather than an edit to your question, and mark it as your answer so the question no longer shows as unanswered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably due to an nginx issue. nginx does not pick up .conf files under the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.

I had to change the file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default and enter the location inside that file. This solved my problem for this question.

The next action item is to check why nginx does not read conf file from /etc/nginx/conf.d directory

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `server` part in upstream is a bit wrong.

Can you try `server 127.0.0.1:5280;` instead of `server ejabberd:5280;` ?

Comment: nginx and ejabberd are running on different docker containers so localhost or 127.0.0.1 will not be useful.